# How do I prove generally that every open set is a union of open intervals?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I've seen proofs using equivalence relations to show that any open subset of the reals is a countable union of disjoint open intervals, but is there a simpler proof to show just that every open set is a union of open intervals without the stipulation that it is a countable union or the open intervals are disjoint? Thanks.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with "general-topology" instead of "metric-spaces" I will give a topological answer - the open intervals are a base for the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, and therefore any open set in $\mathbb R$ can be written as a union of them.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have the definition $$X\text{ is open }\iff \forall x\in X, \exists \varepsilon>0,\ (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq X$$

You can consider the family $\mathcal F=\{(a,b)\subseteq\Bbb R\,:\, (a,b)\subseteq X\}$, i.e. the family of all the open (perhaps even bounded, if you so desire) intervals which are subsets of $X$. Then it is clear that $\bigcup \mathcal F=X$. In fact, $\bigcup\mathcal F\subseteq X$ because all the elements of $\mathcal F$ are subsets of $X$. On the other hand, the hypothesis of $X$ being open implies that every $x\in X$ is element of some element of $\mathcal F$, and therefore it is in $\bigcup \mathcal F$. Which means $\bigcup\mathcal F\supseteq X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an open subset of the real line.

Since every point of $A$ belongs to an open ball which is contained in $A$ , the set A is a subset of the union of these open intervals.

On the other hand since each of these open intervals is contained in $A$ the union of these open intervals is contained in $A$

Thus $A$ is the union of  these open intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this can be done simply by the definition of the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  Open intervals serve as a basis for the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore any open set must be some union of intervals.